# Bash script wont run under sudo crontab but will under pi crontab

Tags: display, cron

I have a simple script `start_chromium.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --kiosk http://server:8080
```

When I do `sudo crontab -e` and add `@reboot /home/pi/start_chromium.sh` to the bottom, it seems ineffective. However, when I do the same with just `crontab -e` (as `pi` user) it works as intended.

I have a vague memory as to why this is the case but I can't recall and would love to learn what the holdup is.

Comment: Trying to do start **ANY** GUI program from cron is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Is this because cron might not run within a GUI environment?

Comment: It ***might*** be possible. Have you looked at [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180798/how-to-set-cron-to-display-gui-application)? - or this [`cron-gui-launcher` project on GitHub?](https://github.com/pa4080/cron-gui-launcher)

Comment: I ended up just uses autostart, thanks! Sometimes it can be overwhelming how many ways there are to do something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to start a GUI app is with autostart. There are many examples on this site.